# Website animations running on mobile but not on PC

Tags: jquery, html, animation, web

I am applying to college and hence was making an online portfolio type website for my self. Its live @ yadullah.coolpage.biz (ignore the domain name, free domains you know)

Its working just fine when I run it locally, but whenever I upload it to the domain and open it, the animations don't load. After a few refreshes however, they start working.
Strange thing is that the website runs just fine when accessed from mobile phones. I've tried my own Blu Win HD LTE running Monument Browser, and a few android models. All the phones on which the site was tested on ran it perfectly. This issue persists on PC only.

All my images are web optimized. By that I mean they are all below 500kb in size. Other than that there's only text on the website. Tried Chrome and Safari, issue persists

The animations I am using are from the Animate on Scroll library. Check it out [here](http://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)

I really can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: What browser are you accessing the site from on PC?

Comment: @AshMenhennett Google Chrome

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript here?

Comment: @AshMenhennett but my java script doesn't control the animations in any way... They are controlled by the AoS library

Comment: Are you passing in any data to the ```init``` method from a ```script``` tag in your HTML? I.e ```AOS.init({ ... });```

Comment: @AshMenhennett I have a seperate js file named `index` in which I have this line `AOS.init({
  duration: 1200
});` I call this js in a script tag inside my html

Comment: I am thinking the problem is that the animations are being disabled on a large viewport. Perhaps try overriding the default ```disable``` property value. Try passing in ```null``` or a condition that will not be met. I.e ```AOS.init({disable: window.innerWidth < 0});```. https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/blob/master/README.md#disabling-aos

Comment: @AshMenhennett then why are the animations working locally?

Comment: My bad. I misread. Check the JavaScript console when you load your site (not locally). Perhaps AOS is not being loaded.

Comment: @AshMenhennett Yes that fixed the issue... But now the animations are way faster

Comment: Just alter the duration property of AOS to fit your preference.

Comment: @AshMenhennett I did... the final statement is this, but the issue reappears when I do this - AOS.init({disable: window.innerWidth < 0, duration: 1200
});

Comment: Are you using any html element attributes like ```data-aos-duration```?

Comment: @AshMenhennett my bad.. the file hadn't uploaded properly... please write that as an answer so that I can mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking the problem is that the animations are being disabled on a large viewport. Perhaps try overriding the default `disable` property value. Try passing in `null` or a condition that will not be met. 
I.e

```
AOS.init({disable: window.innerWidth < 0});
```

Comment: Did that, the now the animations do load, but sometimes they still don't work randomly